# How to detect block devices on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, block-device

With C++ on Linux, how does one detect block devices? Right now, I'm using this code:

```cpp
for (const auto &entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator("/dev/"))
{
    std::string name = entry.path().filename().string();
    if (name.find("sd") == 0 || name.find("nvme") == 0 || name.find("hd") == 0 || name.find("vd") == 0 || name.find("xvd") == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Found device: " << entry.path() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Which works well enough in practice, but almost certainly isn't the way it's "supposed to be done". And it isn't perfect either, as it misses losetup devices because I didn't include `"loop"`, it also misses [Network Block Devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/blockdev/nbd.html) because I didn't include `"nbd"`.

Comment: FYI, instead of using `name.find("sd") == 0`, etc, consider using `name.compare("sd", 2) == 0`, etc instead. Or, in C++20 and later, you can use `name.starts_with("sd")`, etc.

Comment: Better check `/sys/block/`. And note that things like `loop` and `nbd` are created on demand. They don't exist unless in use.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow i need to support Cygwin and Linux, Cygwin supports /dev/sd* but it does not support /sys/block ^^ thanks for the suggestion though.  (the "windows" build [here](https://github.com/divinity76/captester/commit/be027506778a5e86578a2e4603ba7fac2e58a870) is actually just a cygwin static compilation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::filesystem::directory_entry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry) has an [`is_block_file()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/is_block_file) method for this exact purpose:

> Checks whether the pointed-to object is a block device.

For example:

```
for (const auto &entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator("/dev/"))
{
    if (entry.is_block_file())
    {
        std::cout << "Found device: " << entry.path() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do it (untested, no error checking for brevity):

```
const char *maybe_block_device = ...;
struct stat st;
stat (maybe_block_device, &st);
bool is_block_device = S_ISBLK (st.st_mode);
```

Where `S_ISBLK` is a 'helper' macro.

Documentation [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html) and [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html).

Comment: Note that [`directory_entry::status()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/status) is a wrapper for `stat()`, so you don't have to call `stat()` directly, eg: `if (entry.status().type() == file_type::block)`, which can then be simplified using [`directory_entry::is_block_file()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/is_block_file), eg: `if (entry.is_block_file())`

Comment: @RemyLebeau OK, since C++17.

Comment: Yes, which the OP is clearly using

Comment: this is probably what std::filesystem::directory_entry::is_block_file() does under-the-hood :) interesting, thanks

Comment: @hans Has to be.  Maybe the `std::filesystem` variant is portable though, I'm not sure how things stand with MSVC on this.